# How can I create a dynamic while loop?

Tags: loops, kotlin

```
when(cShotCount) {
  in 0..4 -> { // If the total shot count is between 0 and 4
   levelTextView ? .text = "Level: " + 0 // Display level
   editor2?.putInt("levelCount", 0) // Set level
   editor2?.apply()
   mChart.setProgress(((cShotCount?.toFloat()!! - 0) / 5) * 100, true) // Display progress
   mChart.progressColor(Color.BLUE) // Set progress bar color
  }
```

My problem follows:

My "game" has 50 levels. Each level is a range, i.e. 0..4, 5..18, 19..41, etc. Obviously, I don't want to copy/paste the above code 50 times, and then manually change the level display, level count, progress indicator and progress bar color (4 variables).

I thought about creating a list of objects that contain "starting value of range", "ending value of range", "corresponding level value", "value of progress bar", but I'm not sure how I would implement them into the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Level should be an `Object` with those being properties, would seem a lot more tidy.

Comment: Your title says "while loop", the tag says "for-loop" but I don't see any loop in your question. Can you clarify what loop you are talking about? And why did you tag with `java` when the question is about kotlin?

Comment: cShotCount is an Integer that increments every time a score is posted. Though this doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a data class for each level, and put all your levels in a list. Then make a function that does the leveling stuff - you don't want to put all your code in a single loop:

```
data class Level(
    val shotRange: IntRange,
    val level: Int,
    val color: Color
)

val levels = listOf(
    Level(0..4, 0, Color.BLUE)
    // Add all levels
)

fun setLevel(cShotCount: Int) {
    val level = levels.find { cShotCount in it.shotRange }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Shot count out of level range")
    levelTextView.text = "Level: ${level.level}" // Display level
    editor2.putInt("levelCount", 0) // Set level
    editor2.apply()
    mChart.setProgress(cShotCount.toFloat() / (level.shotRange.endInclusive + 1) * 100, true) // Display progress
    mChart.progressColor(level.color) // Set progress bar color
}
```

Then in your loop you can then invoke the `setLevel` function to set the level:

```
var cShotCount = 0
while (true) {
    // Do stuff
    setLevel(cShotCount)
}
```

You may optimize the level searching by putting the levels in a better data structure to optimize searching for the level.
If you have a foreseeable amount of shot counts, you could make an `Array<Level>` indexed by the shotcount to get a fast `O(1)` lookup. Or you could use a tree, do binary searches, etc.